# Locality in COA/Vertex Operator Algebras

Tags: operator-algebras, conformal-field-theory

I am trying to understand CFT from the viewpoint of both math(in particular using VOA) and physics. Now, in Math, we use the VOA to make sense of fields corresponding to certain states. We define for each state, $\lvert a \rangle $, in the Fock space, a field say $V(\lvert a \rangle, z )$ and we then expect these fields to be local, i.e.
\begin{equation}
(z-w)^k \ [ \ V(\lvert a \rangle, z), V(\lvert b \rangle, w ) \ ] = 0
\end{equation}
where they are treating $V(\lvert a \rangle, z)$ and $V(\lvert b \rangle, w)$ to be formal series and both the products, $V(\lvert a \rangle, z)V(\lvert b \rangle, w )$ and $V(\lvert b \rangle, w)V(\lvert a \rangle, z )$ are defined.
This is the standard treatment in texts such as
Vertex Algebras and Algebraic Curves by David Ben-Zvi and Edward Frenkel 
Christoph A. Keller - Introduction to VOA - [https://www.math.arizona.edu/~cakeller/VertexOperatorAlgebras.pdf](https://www.math.arizona.edu/%7Ecakeller/VertexOperatorAlgebras.pdf) \

However, in physics we treat $z$ in Riemann sphere and $V(\lvert a \rangle, z)V(\lvert b \rangle, w )$ is only defined when $\lvert z \lvert \ > \ \lvert w \lvert$. Further, by locality we mean that  $$\langle c \lvert V(\lvert a \rangle, z)V(\lvert b \rangle, w )\lvert d \rangle = \langle c \lvert V(\lvert b \rangle, w)V(\lvert a \rangle, z ) \lvert d \rangle, \  \forall \ \lvert c \rangle,  \lvert d \rangle \in \mathcal{F},$$ after analytic continuation of these functions into regions where they were not defined.

Such definitions can be found for example in https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9410029.

Now, how are these two definitions of locality equivalent. Further, I haven't seen where exactly in Math references they start treating $z$ as complex variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this question is more than a year old I'm sure you found what you were looking for, but since I stumbled across this question I'll answer in case anyone else happens to do the same. Section 1.2.8 of *Vertex Algebras and Algebraic Curves* by Frenkel and Ben-Zvi gives the complex-analytic reformulation of locality of fields that culminates in Proposition 1.2.9, which gives the equivalence between the two definitions. The whole of chapter 1 is a very useful resource for giving analytic meaning to the standard algebraic definitions in math references.